# ssis check if file exists

Tags: c#, ssis

I wanna check using SSIS if there is a  file in a specific folder. I created a Data Flow using an Script Task and Send Mail Task. But it always set like there is no file.

Script Task Code:

```
string FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::vFolderPath"].Value.ToString() +
   Dts.Variables["User::vFileName"].Value.ToString();

if (File.Exists(FilePath))
{
    Dts.Variables["User::vFileExistsFLG"].Value = 1;
}

MessageBox.Show(FilePath);
MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::vFileExistsFLG"].Value.ToString());
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: what is this printing -  MessageBox.Show(FilePath);?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to pad one "\" manually in between like below -

```
    String FilePath=Dts.Variables["User::vFolderPath"].Value.ToString()+ "\\"+ Dts.Variables["User::vFileName"].Value.ToString();
```